# JavaScript Function call returns undefined, why?

Tags: javascript

Hi have the following JavaScript function. When I call it, it returns `undefined`. I would expect it to return an object.  Why does it return `undefined`?

```
function someFunction() {
    return
    {
      name: 'Mary'
    };
  }
```

For example:

https://jsfiddle.net/richardmarais/Lwpygd17/1/

Thanks

Comment: You should not add a break line after return. It returns undefined because javascript interprets your code as `return; { ... } ` . So it will return undefined. Even in the jsfiddle you shared you can see an error on that line. ( the red dot ) . saying `line break error`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`Automatic Semicolon Insertion`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Automatic_Semicolon_Insertion)

> The `return` statement is affected by automatic semicolon insertion (ASI). No line terminator is allowed between the return keyword and the expression.

In JavaScript `return` followed by nothing (in the same line) is evaluated as `return;`

```js
function someFunction() {
  console.log('function called');
  return{
    name: 'Mary'
  };
}

var o = someFunction();
console.log(o);
```

Answer (score 3):

In javascript the `;` is optional.

Therefore, your browser interpretes your code like this :

```
function someFunction() {
    return;   // It adds automatically a semi colon here
    {
      name: 'Mary'
    };
  }
```

So, if you want it to work, you need to do this

```
function someFunction() {
    return{
      name: 'Mary'
    };
  }
```

Comment: Really the semicolon _isn't_ optional. If you miss them out the they are inserted by the ASI routine which is an _error correction routine_.

Comment: @Andy Don't you think it might depend on your point of view? From a dev point of view, you don't really need semicolons, do you? If you look at JS grammar, you will see a dev does not need to add a semicolon everywhere. (I won't say it's a good idea)