# Mute system discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Hello I have problem with my code! When I use my mute command it always spams "You need permission to use command"! Here is my code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.content.startsWith("$mute")) {
    if (!message.member.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS")) return
    message.channel.send("You need permissions to use command")
    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted")
    let member = message.mentions.members.first()
    let reason = message.content.split(" ").slice(2).join(" ")
    if(!reason) return message.channel.send("You didn't write a reason")
    if(!role) return message.channel.send("This server don't have Muted role")
    if(!member) return message.channel.send("You didn't mention the user to mute!")

    member.roles.add(role)
    .then(() => {
      message.channel.send(`Successfully muted ${member} with reason: ${reason}`)
    })
    .catch(() => {
      message.channel.send("Error")
    })
 }
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript Function call returns undefined, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57866395/javascript-function-call-returns-undefined-why)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
if (!message.member.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS"))  return
message.channel.send("You need permissions to use command")
```

This translates to "If the member doesn't have the permission to kick other members, exit the function and return *undefined*. Else, if the member HAS permission, send a message saying he DOESN'T have permission".

```js
if (!message.member.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("You need permissions to use command")
```

You should write it like this instead.